# how can you calculate the size of an apache spark data frame using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to calculate the size in bytes of an Apache spark Data Frame using pyspark?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to learn from this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008123/how-to-find-spark-rdd-dataframe-size

Comment: I'm trying to limit the number of output files when exporting the data frame by repartitioning it based on its size.

Comment: Here's a possible workaround. You can easily find out how many rows you're dealing with using a `df.count()` then use `df.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10000).save(file/path/)` to get the exact number of output files you want. It also saves you a very costly `repartition`. Would this help ?

Answer (score 3):

why don't you just cache the df and then look in the spark UI under storage and convert the units to bytes

```
df.cache()
```