# Estimate Spark DataSet by partition size - uncompressed

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

In my application, I have a spark dataset of X rows
I have different CSV files each one with different size and structure.
I'm generating a Dataset over this CSV's.

Before posting this question I saw these questions:

- [How can I find the size of a RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397777/how-can-i-find-the-size-of-a-rdd?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [how can you calculate the size of an apache spark data frame using pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180140/how-can-you-calculate-the-size-of-an-apache-spark-data-frame-using-pyspark)
- [How to find spark RDD/Dataframe size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008123/how-to-find-spark-rdd-dataframe-size)
- [How to get a sample with an exact sample size in Spark RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837530/how-to-get-a-sample-with-an-exact-sample-size-in-spark-rdd?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I need to calculate the size of each partition during runtime
The result of the files are ORC(snappy compression)

all of the above questions offering to use Size Estimator

So I also read about [Size Estimator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/SizeEstimator.html)

When i did try to use this Size Estimator of the

```
SizeEstimator.estimate(dataFrame.rdd().partitions())
```

I got this results: 71.124 MB, I have also try to use `estimate` of a sample with partials file reading - which results in the same size.

Seeing this result - just don't make sense, Here some more details:

```
Source file size 44.8 KB (CSV) - 300 rows.

SizeEstimator.estimate(dataSet.rdd().partitions()) 71.124 MB
```

The actual data frame results on run time are stored to S3:

```
dataSet.write().partitionBy(partitionColumn).option("header", "true").mode(SaveMode.Append).format("snappy").save(pathTowrite);
```

- I would like to know the actual size of the dataFrame file without
  the compression
- I rather not read the file from S3 after saving it:
- it's compressed - and not the real size.
          not best resource planning.

  1. How come there is such a huge difference between SizeEstimator and the real size of the file, is this make sense ?
  2. Is there other efficient way of estimate each partition data size (uncompressed) prior to saving it ?

my entire code is in Java- so java solution is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I was able to use a temp solution which is not efficient but quite close to what I need

[Spark DataSet efficiently get length size of entire row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423462/spark-dataset-efficiently-get-length-size-of-entire-row)