# Timeout of PySpark countApprox() is not working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with Pyspark and Dataframes and I would like to know approximately if a Dataframe is greater than something.

I'm trying to use `countApprox()` function:

```
 df.rdd.countApprox(1000, 0.5)
```

But seems that in Pyspark the timeout is not working. I've seen that in Scala/Java the function is returning an object where you can check "low" and "high" values, but in Pyspark is returning only an integer. When the Dataframe is "big" is taking like minutes to get the `countApprox()` even if I put the timeout to 1000 milliseconds

Does anyone know if `countApprox()` works different or if is there any other function to know an approximation of the size of the Dataframe instead of the number of rows? I only need to know if a Dataframe is "very small" or "very big".

Thanks.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: "very big", "small", etc is opinion based. Maybe what your looking for is here: [How to find spark RDD/Dataframe size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008123/how-to-find-spark-rdd-dataframe-size)