# Size of Scala array by byte

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a very large array with 10 dataframe inside whit contain around 
thousands of input(from hive dataset).
how could I know the size of this array by bytes?

Comment: @user8371915 I think it's not because the post you put above is asking about lenght of input, and I'm asking about the disk size, pls check again

Comment: Please check the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35122573/8371915) (and the question).

Comment: @user8371915 ok it seems like it solved my problem, thank you